# Meaning of "You do not own that mountpoint" when switching to and from root?

Tags: linux, debian, mount, media

I recently installed a new debian OS (replacing my old ubuntu) and kept the same home directory. Whenever I switch into and out of root (via the su command) I get a message that says "You do not own that mountpoint." What is the meaning of this message and how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, the user ID for your regular user in the Debian installation is not the same as your user ID for your regular user in the previous Ubuntu installation.  The way to fix this is to call the following on your home directory:

```
chown -R <user>:<user> <home>
```

Replace `<user>` with your user name and `<home>` with the path to your home directory.

Also, slightly OT, but it would be a good idea to start using `sudo` instead of `su` (`su` has a bunch of known security issues and also isn't the most reliable thing around).